# Is there a single word to describe someone who relies on their appearance for advantage?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe someone who relies on their appearance for advantage?

For example: Newscasters often tend to be ____________ because of the visual nature of their industry.

Jill's parents thought she was an adorable little girl, but worried that she might become a ____________.

NOTE: I am not looking for a word to describe someone obsessed with their appearance, (narcissist), but for someone who relies on their appearance.

Comment: Hmm tough one, the closest thing I can think of is image-conscious but that's not a single word and doesn't necessarily denote reliance.

Comment: Not a single word: "*obsessed with her/their look*".

Comment: a Kardashian, perhaps?

Comment: @rhetorician: *kardashian* is a great **adjective** for this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, **appearance-minded**.

> *They are appearance minded, buy clothing at midtier department stores and specialty stores, get professional manicures and pedicures, and
> buy hair care products from salons.* [Sage Publications - School of
> Journalism and Mass
> Communication](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=37&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEUQFjAGOB5qFQoTCNnNiaSpz8gCFcg9FAod9VEF8Q&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.journalism.wisc.edu%2F%7Edshah%2FANNALS2007b.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHDbns8u0e1epHNCAUgmUWAxt2XzA)
>
> *Newscasters often tend to be **appearance-minded** because of the visual nature of their industry.*
>
> *Jill's parents thought she was an adorable
> little girl, but worried that she might become **appearance-minded**.*

Answer (score 1):

The word is "fop", as in "a man who is excessively vain and concerned about his dress, appearance, and manners."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fop?s=t

Comment: A dandy answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples of different words in place.  Note that the meanings of the two examples are slightly different so some words may not cross over between them. These three work quite well though:

- Newscasters often tend to be **vain** because of the visual nature of their industry.
- Newscasters often tend to be **shallow** because of the visual nature of their industry.
- Newscasters often tend to be **narcissistic** because of the visual nature of their industry.

---

- Jill's parents thought she was an adorable little girl, but worried that she might become **vain**.
- Jill's parents thought she was an adorable little girl, but worried that she might become **shallow**.
- Jill's parents thought she was an adorable little girl, but worried that she might become **narcissistic**.

---

These two, while they do encompass the concept, do have masculine connotations, so aren't really appropriate for this specific sentence:

- Jill's parents thought she was an adorable little girl, but worried that she might become a **popinjay**.
- Jill's parents thought she was an adorable little girl, but worried that she might become a **fop**.